# Zabbix JMX Tomcat monitoring

Tags: zabbix

I have been trying to setup Zabbix to monitor my 2 tomcat servers on 2 different Amazon EC2 machines, but in vain. 

 
 The Z on the host is green, however te JMX is red with these errors 
- ZBX_TCP_READ() failed: [4] Interrupted system call 
- Someother error [111] connection refused
and many such errors, one after another, in the sense I resolve an error to see one more new error popping up.

These are some assumptions 
All the machines run Ubuntu 12.10 and later 
**Server's IP address:** 66.55.12.120 (Runs Zabbix server v2.2.4 (revision 46772) (23 June 2014) ) 
**Agent's IP address:** 87.52.45.198 ( Runs Zabbix agent v2.2.2 (revision 42525) (12 February 2014) ) 
**My local machine's IP address:** 76.89.54.111

Here  is what I've done so far.

***On Server Side:*** 
1) Installed Zabbix_server using `sudo apt-get install zabbix-server-mysql.` 
2) The GUI, mysql database all have been installed and configured. 
3) The following are the only 3 changes that I've made in the file 
 `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf`

```
  ... 
  JavaGateway=localhost
  JavaGatewayPort=10052
  StartJavaPollers=5
  ...
```

4) The Zabbix Java gateway was installed using `sudo apt-get install zabbix-java-gateway.`
5) The following are the only 3 changes that I've made in the file 
  `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_java_gateway.conf`

```
  ... 
  LISTEN_IP="127.0.0.1"
  LISTEN_PORT=10052
  START_POLLERS=5
  ...
```

***On Client Side:***
1) Installed Zabbix Client using
   `sudo apt-get install zabbix-agent` 
2) The following are the only 3 changes that I've made in the file

```
  /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf 
  ... 
  Server=66.55.12.120
  StartAgents=5
  ServerActive=66.55.12.120:10051
  Hostname=Security-test-JMX-EC2
  ... <br />
```

3) The Hostname is the same as the one that is mentioned while creating the Host on the GUI.

I believe that there are some issues with the IP and ports. So, here are the outbound rules for both the machines as obtained from Amazon EC2 Security Groups for the machines

```
OUTBOUND RULES for SERVER SECURITY GROUP:
Type      Protocol  Port   Source           Reasoning
Custom-   TCP       8080   0.0.0.0/0
TCP Rule    

All ICMP  All       N/A    0.0.0.0/0    

Custom-   TCP       10052  27.52.52.128/32   For access from Agent
TCP Rule

Custom-   TCP       8081   76.84.120.130/32  To access Zabbix GUI from-
TCP Rule                                     -my local machine's web browser

Custom-   TCP       10051  27.52.52.128/32   As the agent responds to- 
TCP Rule                                     -the server on Port 10051TCP Rule-
                                             -Must allow inbound communications-
                                             - from the agent.

Custom-   TCP       11000  27.52.52.128/32   The agent's JMX reporting-
TCP Rule                                     -happens on port 11000(not on 12345).

OUTBOUND RULES for CLIENT SECURITY GROUP:
Type    Protocol Port   Source
HTTPS     TCP   443     0.0.0.0/0

Custom-   TCP   10050   66.55.12.120/32
TCP Rule

Custom-   TCP   10052   66.55.12.120/32
TCP Rule

Custom-   TCP   11000   66.55.12.120/32
TCP Rule

HTTP      TCP   80  76.89.54.111/32

Custom-   TCP   8080    76.89.54.111/32
TCP Rule

Custom-   TCP   8443    76.89.54.111/32
TCP Rule
```

What am I missing? Please guide me.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks 
Goutham

Answer (score 7):

If you can, then run VisualVm (probably using a tunneled X session) on the zabbix host, and see if you can connect to the target JVM with that.  If you can't connect from that, you won't be able to connect from Zabbix.

Try with the following CATALINA_OPTS, replacing  with the IP on the target that you want JMX to listen on:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=falseom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<LOCAL_IP>"
```

This will disable all JMX security so be aware!

Once you hopefully get it to connect, the "Tomcat JMX" items in Zabbix are also all incorrect! e.g.

**Incorrect Zabbix default:**

`jmx["Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=http-8080",bytesReceived]`

**Correct entry:**

`jmx["Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name=\"http-bio-8080\"", bytesReceived]`

Note the escaped quotes and incorrect thread name.  Add the Mbeans plugin to VisualVM, and use that to browse the MBeans on the target VM, and check the Zabbix names.

It does work eventually, but is a real pain to setup.  Zabbix is however one of the few open source monitoring tools that supports JMX at all!

Comment: Instead of installing VisualVm, I was able to connect using `jconsole`, which was already installed on my system.  `jconsole` appears to a standard part of the JDK (source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JConsole).

Comment: `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<LOCAL_IP>` did the trick.
Good one!

Comment: Your answer just saved my day. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

By default, JMX does not work very well with firewalls. You might find related bug reports on Zabbix tracker useful: [ZBX-5326](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-5326) and [ZBX-6815](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-6815). The first one contains a workaround for Tomcat which might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

@gvatreya wrote:

> Server: (Runs Zabbix server)
>
> Agent:  (Runs Zabbix agent)

It looks like you have to **start** Zabbix Java gateway as well on host where it is installed (it is a daemon/service).

I configured as follows:

> Server: (Runs Zabbix server, Zabbix Java gateway)
>
> Agent:  (Runs Zabbix agent)

I think it is possible to install it on a dedicated host.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to the VM options?

Comment: How would this help? What does it do? Any reference?

Comment: If you're using Java 8 on a RHEL/CentOS 7.x, port 10051/10052 will be listening on tcp6 stack. By forcing tcp(4) and having the port open in firewalld, you'll have your agent (e.g zapcat) properly connected to the server.

Answer (score 0):

to make it work add next java_opts to your tomcat startup script

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=2345 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=12345 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<tomcat_hostname>
```