# Zabbix Tomcat monitoring GC

Tags: tomcat, monitoring, jmx, zabbix

I have problem with monitoring few things on tomcat, specificaly GrabageCollectionAggregator and CPU monitoring. As in image i tried many combinations of \"\", added name=, etc but still it does not work...
 with other items this thread helped me [jmx-tomcat-monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862967/zabbix-jmx-tomcat-monitoring), because default template is broken.

Here is img [image]

Comment: Please show the key of an item that works for you in this Tomcat instance.

Comment: jmx["java.lang:type=Memory","HeapMemoryUsage.used"] works perfectly and i found out that CPU sometimes gets the value but then became not supported..

Comment: What is the error message when it becomes unsupported? If it's about value type, try setting it to "Numeric (float)".

Comment: @Richlv well processCpuLoad works somehow but HeapLiveSet is still not Supported with error: com.sun.management:type=GarbageCollectionAggregator

Comment: I think problem might be with com.sun.management because everything else works. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I recall fixing something similar a long time ago, but don't recall the details. Any useful messages in the Java gateway log? If not, try increasing the verbosity of that log.

Answer (score 0):

HeapLiveSet is a synthetic item - in other words it's a client side calculated value. Those items can not be requested directly via jmx but you can calculate it yourself with all the values under LastGcInfo.

[image: Oracle Java Mission Control]